# Is there a in built method from python csv module to enumerate all possible value for a specific column?

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I have a csv file which has many columns. Now my requirement is to find all possible value that are present for that specific column.

Is there any built in function in python that helps me to get these values.

Comment: Question not clear: You have many columns and you want to find all possible value that are present for "that" column? which column ? you have many

Comment: @Ramast I have modified it.

Comment: @Apoorvasahay did any of the answers below provide a solution for you? If so please select one as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Example file `many_cols.csv`:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,10,100
1,20,100
2,10,100
3,30,100
```

Find unique values per column:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('many_cols.csv')
>>> df.col1.drop_duplicates().tolist()
[1, 2, 3]
>>> df['col2'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
[10, 20, 30]
>>> df['col3'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
[100]
```

For all columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('many_cols.csv')

for col in df.columns:
    print(col, df[col].drop_duplicates().tolist())
```

Output:

```
col1 [1, 2, 3]
col2 [10, 20, 30]
col3 [100]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [set()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set) for this.

Lets say the csv file is this and we want only unique values from second column.

```
foo,1,bar
baz,2,foo
red,3,blue
git,3,foo
```

Here is the code that would accomplish this. I am simply printing out the unique values to test that it worked.

```py
import csv

def parse_csv_file(rawCSVFile):
    fileLineList = []

    with open(rawCSVFile, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            fileLineList.append(row)

    return fileLineList

def main():
    uniqueColumnValues = set() 
    fileLineList = parse_csv_file('sample.csv')

    for row in fileLineList:
        uniqueColumnValues.add(row[1]) # Selecting 2nd column here.

    print(uniqueColumnValues)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Overly "clever" approach to figuring out unique values for all the rows at once (assumes all columns are the same size, though it ignores empty lines seamlessly):

```
# Assumes somefile was opened properly earlier
csvin = filter(None, csv.reader(somefile))
for i, vals in enumerate(map(sorted, map(set, zip(*csvin)))):
    print("Unique values for column", i)
    print(vals)
```

It uses `zip(*csvin)` to do a table rotation (converting the normal one row at a time output to one column at a time), then uniquifies each column with `set`, and (for nice output) sorts it.